# SQL query does not return the correct results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    r.sequence, r.status, r.title, r.duedate, 
    r.related_customer, r.added_by 
FROM
    reminders r, reminders_users ru 
WHERE 
    r.sequence = ru.reminder_seq 
    AND (ru.type = 'user' AND ru.value = '2') 
     OR (ru.value = 'admin' OR ru.value = 'technical_support' 
         OR ru.value = 'sales' OR ru.value = 'accounts') 
    AND r.sequence > '0' 
ORDER BY 
    field(status, '', 'Completed'), duedate ASC
```

However its returning results where `ru.value = '3'`

The rows that are being returned are:

```
reminders.sequence = '883'

reminders_users.reminder_seq = '883'
reminders_users.type = 'user'
reminders_users.value = '3'
```

i cannot see how it is showing this as the `reminders_users.value = '3'` and not `'2'`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your OR in your WHERE means you can get stuff out with values different than 2

Comment: Protip: [**Operator Precedence**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html). Use round bracket, remove comma join.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen but its not equal to any of the where conditions?

Comment: You should always add parens when mixing `AND` and `OR`. The precedence is `NOT` - `AND` - `OR`. This your current condition: (r.sequence = ru.reminder_seq 
    AND (ru.type = 'user' AND ru.value = '2')) 
     OR ((ru.value = 'admin' OR ru.value = 'technical_support' 
         OR ru.value = 'sales' OR ru.value = 'accounts') 
    AND r.sequence > '0')

Comment: Additionally `value` and `sequence` are probably numeric columns, thus quoting values is just useless, e.g. `reminders.sequence = 883`

Comment: so what should the query be?

Comment: It's obvious that you are mixing AND and OR without appropriate parentheses, but I dont't see how you can get any value other than '2', 'admin', 'technical_support', 'sales', and 'accounts'.

Comment: Do you have multiple entries in your reminders_users table with the same reminder_seq?
Please execute:
SELECT * FROM reminders_users WHERE reminder_seq = '883';

Comment: @GreenTurtle yes there could be

Comment: @GreenTurtle although this particular query will only be looking at the one row in that table

Comment: Ok, then you should try to select the relevant reminders_users fields within your SELECT statement above and you will see, that no ru.value = '3' is contained:
SELECT 
    r.sequence, r.status, r.title, r.duedate, 
    r.related_customer, r.added_by, ru.type, ru.value
FROM
    reminders r, reminders_users ru  .....

Comment: i see, its returning a different ru.type and ru.value which do not exist against ru.reminder_seq =  '883' - so it looks like its not matching the r.sequence = ru.reminder_seq

Comment: That would be strange. Please add the column ru.reminder_seq as well to your selected result columns and my bet is r.sequence matches ru.reminder_seq in all cases.

Comment: the reminder_seq is showing as 922 - so thats the problem. i am going to try using a JOIN instead and see if that works

Comment: Seeing that your ANDs and ORs are not properly written, what *is* the desired criteria actually? I suppose: *Every* result record must obey `r.sequence > '0'` and additionally either ru.value is '2' with type 'user' or ru.value is one of 'admin', 'technical_support', 'sales', 'accounts', no matter what type. Is that so?

Comment: The considered values in `ru.value` look strange by the way. You expect it to hold jobs like 'admin' and 'technical_support' on the one hand and numbers like '2' on the other. I don't say it's wrong; it only looks weird. Maybe you confused type and value in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the values '2', 'user', 'admin', etc., you probably confused the columns value and type. Moreover when mixing AND and OR make sure you get your parentheses straight.

Apart from that use explicit joins rather than the long out-dated comma-separated join syntax, don't use quotes on numbers and use IN instead of several ORs on the same field.

```
SELECT 
  r.sequence, r.status, r.title, r.duedate, 
  r.related_customer, r.added_by 
FROM reminders r
JOIN reminders_users ru ON r.sequence = ru.reminder_seq 
WHERE r.sequence > 0
AND
(
  (ru.value = 'user' AND ru.type = 2) 
  OR 
  ru.value IN ('admin', 'technical_support', 'sales', 'accounts')
)  
ORDER BY field(status, '', 'Completed'), duedate ASC;
```